# Remove space/spaces between two words

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I want this out come

```
Input              =|= Output  
=============================================
[b] [/b]           =|= [b][/b]
[b]      [/b]      =|= [b][/b]
[b]Hii[/b]         =|= [b]Hii[/b]  
[b]Hello There[/b] =|= [b]Hello There[/b]
```

*I think the only way to solve this problem is regex which i dont know to write, so looking for help*

Comment: on the last example, do you still want the space between "Hello" and "There"?

Comment: Yes, want the space between words

Comment: Ok - I won't edit my answer because it looks like you have a few options to choose from and someone might find this looking for a generic space replacing js snippet - I like @mVChr solution

Comment: for your case you don't need regex in php see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = input.replace(/\[b\]\s+\[\/b\]/ig, '[b][/b]');
```

[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/PjfWy/)

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript:

```
input = input.replace(/\[b\](?:&nbsp;|\s)+?\[\/b\]/gi, '[b][/b]');
```

For PHP:

```
$input = preg_replace('/\[b\](?:&nbsp;|\s)+?\[\/b\]/i', '[b][/b]', $input);
```

The above includes `&nbsp;` since the example formerly showed that. If there is no need, just use:

For JavaScript:

```
input = input.replace(/\[b\]\s+?\[\/b\]/gi, '[b][/b]');
```

For PHP:

```
$input = preg_replace('/\[b\]\s+?\[\/b\]/i', '[b][/b]', $input);
```

But these will only catch empty whitespace not trailing.

To catch trailing...

For JavaScript:

```
input = input.replace(/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/gi, function (n0, n1) {
    return '[b]' + n1.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') + '[/b]';
});
```

For PHP:

```
$input = preg_replace_callback('/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/i', 
    create_function(
        '$m',
        'return "[b]".trim($m[1])."[/b]";'
    ), 
    $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.replace(/\s+/g,'')` will take out all spaces (which it sounds like what you are trying to do) even though your last example confuses me

Answer (score 0):

Um.. I think I get what you mean when I read your question, but your example confused me a lot.
You have both PHP & Javascript written...
IF you wanna do this is PHP use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
$str = 'the value you want to parse';

$new_value = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $str);

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
preg_replace ("/\s+/", "\s", $subject);
preg_replace ("/\]\s+\[/", "\]\[", $subject);
```

It could be done with a single regex, but it's much easier to understand in 2 passes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to get rid of the spaces before and after your string only.

In php there is a native function that does just that

`trim()`
[Read here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
Here is an example:

$string = ' Hello World!      ';

$trimmed = trim($string);

echo $trimmed;
// will print 'Hello World'
```